# unable to run react app via ExpoGo on Iphone

Tags: react-native

I was trying to run app via Expo Go on iPhone,
but in Expo Go is missing option to put URL or QR scan.
on Android is working OK.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Just scan via iphone's default Camera app.

Comment: So is this some bug, that there is no option eneter URL or scan QR code ?
Unfortunately i dont have  test device to check it.

Comment: Not sure! It might be related to the fact the iPhone already has built-in QR code scan and needs permissions to access camera within the app.